# Accepting both file paths and URL in Java

Tags: java, url, uri

Is there a method which would accept the following paths and return appropriate URI:

```
test.xml // File in CWD
./test.xml // The same
../test.xml // File in parent directory
/etc/test.xml // Absolute path
file:///etc/test.xml // Full URL
http://example.com/test.xml // URL for http
```

Currently all I can think of is parse as url (URL.create) and if it fails attempt to try to parse it as File/Path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use those `URI`s, for example in `File` constructor, you need to specify base `URI` for relative paths. You can do it with [URI.resolve](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#resolve%28java.lang.String%29).

```
URI basePath = new URI("file:///base_dir/");
URI uri = basePath.resolve("foo.txt");

System.out.println(new File(uri));
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried using `URI.resolve` but I've mixed the `this`/argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use [URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html), not URL.

This may or may not be what you actually *want*, however, depending on what you need to do with the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an URI for each of the resources you pointed as follows:

```
public class T {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        System.out.println(new URI("test.xml"));
        System.out.println(new URI("./test.xml"));
        System.out.println(new URI("../test.xml"));
        System.out.println(new URI("/etc/test.xml"));
        System.out.println(new URI("file:///etc/test.xml"));
        System.out.println(new URI("http://example.com/test.xml"));

    }

}
```

Additionally, you can retrieve the URL with the method "toURL()", but this just in case of the URI is absolute.